# parse ImageMagick histogram string output with php

Tags: php, regex, imagemagick

When running this shell command using passthru:

```
convert example.pdf -threshold 50% -format %c histogram:info:- 2>/dev/null
```

I get a string like this in my PHP script:

```
12422: ( 0, 0, 0)   black 488568: (255,255,255) white
```

I want to end up with a PHP array like this:

Array
(
    [black] => 12422,
    [white] => 488568
)

Can anyone show me an efficient way to do this in PHP?

The output running this on the shell is formatted like
196: (  0,  0,  0)  black
500794: (255,255,255)   white

Thanks

Comment: What regular expressions have you tried? It should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compact version with one regex:

```
<?php
    $string = '12422: ( 0, 0, 0)   black 488568: (255,255,255) white';
    $newarray = array();
    preg_match_all('/([\d]*?):.*?\(.*?\)[ ]*?([^\d]*)/i', $string, $regs, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    for ($xi = 0; $xi < count($regs); $xi++) {
        $newarray[trim($regs[$xi][2])] = trim($regs[$xi][1]);
    }
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($newarray); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Result:

> array(2) {
>       ["black"]=>string(5) "12422"
>       ["white"]=>string(6) "488568"
>   }

Comment: This works too :) But not with my output from passthru.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.. Hope this works...

```
    $string='12422: ( 0, 0, 0)   black 488568: (255,255,255) white';
    preg_match_all('/([\d]+.*?[a-zA-Z]+)/',$string,$matches);   
    $result=array();
    foreach($matches[1] as $value)
    {
        preg_match('/[\w]+$/',$value,$matches1);
        preg_match('/^[\d]+/',$value,$matches2);
        $result[$matches1[0]]=$matches2[0];
    }
    print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work when I pass the $string like in your example, but when I use the output from my passthru command it fails. I think maybe there are newline/CR between the results.

Comment: Work around using shell_exec instead of passhtru, and then removing the control characters using  preg_replace('~[[:cntrl:]]~', '', $string)